# Raspberry - Why I cannot execute the node instantly from the /opt/nodejs/bin/?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I downloaded the NodeJS armv6l archiv to the /opt folder.
If I navigate to the nodearmv6/bin/ there is node,npm and npx avaible, why I can't run them instantly from there?
Somehow it works after I export the /opt/nodearmv6/bin PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your operating system tries to run binary files from the folders, which are defined in the $PATH variable.
run `echo $PATH` to look at that folders.
`export` command adds new folder to $PATH variable.
to solve the problem you can add the symlink of your node, npm, and another files you want to run to /usr/local/bin folder or another folder, which is defined in the $PATH variable.
If you want to run instantly from folder, you have to run your binaries this way `./node` or `./npm install....`

Comment: else he doesn't run them as binary files?

Comment: for example if you want to run npm, you do this: cd /opt/nodearmv6/bin, then ./npm

Comment: the easiest way is to create symlinks for binaries `ln -s /opt/nodearmv6/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node` others are similar. then just run from terminal node, npm, ...